# How to import products/categories in magento1.8.0.0 from oscommerce 2.3.2

Tags: magento-1.8, importexport

I have Online Store setup in Oscommerce 2.3.2 with more than 15000 products, now i want to migrate my store from oscommerce to latest version of magento (i.e. magento 1.8.0.0).

Is there any way that i can achieve functionality like export products/categories from oscommerce and import products/categories in magento?

Comment: Did you manage to resolve your issue? In case you did don't forget to close the question :)

Comment: There is no easy way to take one platform's products and categories and plug them into Magneto. Writing the Mageto code is easy, but porting can sometimes be troublesome. Depending on the source, it could take from one or two days to weeks.

Answer (score 2):

There is a simple tool created by Magento core team that Migrates you OScommerce data to magento. (It also works for Zencart - because ZenCart is an OsCommerce fork project.)

See more info here. I used this for Mage 1.7 and it was done successfully

http://turnkeye.com/blog/migration-zencart-oscommerce-magento/

Answer (score 0):

I know it's frowned upon to promote a paid service or extension but in this case I'm gonna do it anyway.

For any cross platform data transfer I use [cart2cart](http://www.shopping-cart-migration.com/). Writing an import/export like that yourself takes a lot of time and requires you to have a good understanding of both platforms.

If you do want to build it yourself you'll have to find an extension that exports from OScommerce and then map it to, for example, the Magento Dataflow format.

Comment: We have not used it personally but agree Cart2Cart is your best option. Never did understand that, technically cart2cart competes with our products, but if it fulfills >80% of the requirement including cost/time/functionality, which in this case cart2cart does, then it should not matter if it is paid or free.

Answer (score 0):

When we moved from OSCommerce to Magento EE, we used RapidFlow to import products and categories and everythign else.

I wasn't with the team at the time, and while it's paid, its probably a lot more work than cart2cart